# Remove attribute from tag with uBlock Origin

Tags: html, adblock

How can i remove an attribute from a tag using uBlock?

For example in the following `div` i want to remove the `hidden` attribute

```
<div class="test" hidden="hidden">some content</div>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<div class="test">some content</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use uBlock's Static filter syntax [scriptlet injection](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#scriptlet-injection). You have the list of available filters in the uBlock's [Resources-Library](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Resources-Library).

In your case, you can use [remove-attr.js](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Resources-Library#rajs-), from the documentation:

> **remove-attr.js**
>
> Removes attribute(s) from DOM tree node(s). Will run only once after page load.

Regarding your question, you can remove `hidden` attribute from the `div` adding in your uBlock *My Filters*:

```
example.com##+js(ra.js, hidden, div.test)
```

In case you want to remove another attribute, then change `hidden` by the attribute you want to remove, and `div.test` by the CSS selector of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

In the current version of uBlock origin you can use `remove-attr`.

```
example.com##div.test:remove-attr(hidden)
```

Source: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#subjectremove-attrarg-subjectremove-classarg

Comment: Note that there is also a `remove-class()` operation as well.