# Remove class from <body> dynamically using uBlock Origin

Tags: adblock

During browsing when I click an element

```
<body>
```

changes to

```
<body class="xyz">
```

Is it possible to remove this class dynamically using uBlock Origin? Expected behavior: when I click this element, `<body>` does not change.
remove-attr.js (suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656322/remove-attribute-from-tag-with-ublock-origin)) does not work because class "xyz" is not present at the time when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can be done using [rc.js](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Resources-Library#rcjs-).

```
www.example.com##+js(rc, class1|class2, [target], [behavior])
```

Comment: According to the provided link, this is now deprecated in favor of @dragonfire's answer belo.

Answer (score 10):

For those looking to remove the class **on pageload**, you can now use the `:remove-class(class)` action operator in uBlock. There is also `:remove-attr(attr)` as well.

```
www.example.com##body:remove-class(xyz)
```

Wiki article: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#subjectremove-attrarg-subjectremove-classarg

---

If the class only appears **later** (e.g. dynamically on click), try prepending with the `watch-attr(arg)` filter:

```
www.example.com##body:watch-attr(class):remove-class(xyz)
```

Wiki article: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Procedural-cosmetic-filters#subjectwatch-attrarg